# ¿editar mi pregunta o preguntar de nuevo?

Tags: discusión

buenas, al dia siguiente de haber publicado una pregunta me di cuenta que estaba mal explicada pues no exprese de buena manera lo que intentaba hacer con el codigo y cual era exactamente mi problema.

y no se si editarla para explicar mejor lo que intentaba de hacer o repreguntarla con las ediciones hechas.

lo que me mantiene al filo es que recibi una respuesta, una respuesta buena la cual perderia toda coherencia y sentido si modifico la pregunta.

Comment: Cuando tengas dudas, siempre pensá en qué sería lo mejor para favorecer la calidad de respuestas que se encuentran en el sitio.

Answer (score 6):

Si la respuesta actual sirve para la pregunta actual, mi recomendación es que aceptes la respuesta y realices una nueva pregunta.

**Extra:** Si puedes mejorar la pregunta actual, agregando detalles que mejoren la comprensión tanto de la pregunta como de la respuesta para futuras usuarios, sería un valor añadido de tu parte que la comunidad te agradecerá.